# installing SVN on freenas server errors

Tags: svn, freebsd

I have the updated version of freenas 8.0.2.  As root user I run the command "pkg_add -r subversion"

It starts fetching from the ftp server and a series of commands start streaming down the screen.. I see a lot of word "failed" shown below

It seems most people do not have a problem running "pkg_add -r subversion", it just works for them.  I dont know why its different in my case.

Thanks.

```
include/neon/ne_acl3744.h: Failed to create dir 'include/neon'Can't create 'include/ne                                                            on/ne_acl3744.h'
include/neon/ne_alloc.h: Failed to create dir 'include/neon'Can't create 'include/neon                                                            /ne_alloc.h'
include/neon/ne_auth.h: Failed to create dir 'include/neon'Can't create 'include/neon/                                                            ne_auth.h'
include/neon/ne_basic.h: Failed to create dir 'include/neon'Can't create 'include/neon                                                            /ne_basic.h'
include/neon/ne_compress.h: Failed to create dir 'include/neon'Can't create 'include/n                                                            eon/ne_compress.h'
include/neon/ne_dates.h: Failed to create dir 'include/neon'Can't create 'include/neon                                                            /ne_dates.h'
include/neon/ne_defs.h: Failed to create dir 'include/neon'Can't create 'include/neon/                                                            ne_defs.h'
include/neon/ne_i18n.h: Failed to create dir 'include/neon'Can't create 'include/neon/                                                            ne_i18n.h'
include/neon/ne_locks.h: Failed to create dir 'include/neon'Can't create 'include/neon                                                            /ne_locks.h'
include/neon/ne_md5.h: Failed to create dir 'include/neon'Can't create 'include/neon/n                                                            e_md5.h'
include/neon/ne_props.h: Failed to create dir 'include/neon'Can't create 'include/neon                                                            /ne_props.h'
include/neon/ne_redirect.h: Failed to create dir 'include/neon'Can't create 'include/n                                                            eon/ne_redirect.h'
include/neon/ne_request.h: Failed to create dir 'include/neon'Can't create 'include/ne                                                            on/ne_request.h'
include/neon/ne_session.h: Failed to create dir 'include/neon'Can't create 'include/ne                                                            on/ne_session.h'
include/neon/ne_socket.h: Failed to create dir 'include/neon'Can't create 'include/neo                                                            n/ne_socket.h'
include/neon/ne_ssl.h: Failed to create dir 'include/neon'Can't create 'include/neon/n                                                            e_ssl.h'
include/neon/ne_string.h: Failed to create dir 'include/neon'Can't create 'include/neo                                                            n/ne_string.h'
include/neon/ne_uri.h: Failed to create dir 'include/neon'Can't create 'include/neon/n                                                            e_uri.h'
include/neon/ne_utils.h: Failed to create dir 'include/neon'Can't create 'include/neon                                                            /ne_utils.h'
include/neon/ne_xml.h: Failed to create dir 'include/neon'Can't create 'include/neon/n                                                            e_xml.h'
include/neon/ne_xmlreq.h: Failed to create dir 'include/neon'Can't create 'include/neo                                                            n/ne_xmlreq.h'
include/neon/ne_pkcs11.h: Failed to create dir 'include/neon'Can't create 'include/neo                                                            n/ne_pkcs11.h'
lib/libneon.so.27: Could not unlink
lib/libneon.so: Could not unlink
lib/libneon.la: Could not unlink
lib/libneon.a: Could not unlink
libdata/pkgconfig/neon.pc: Could not unlink
share/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/neon.mo: Could not unlink
share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/neon.mo: Could not unlink
share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/neon.mo: Could not unlink
share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/neon.mo: Could not unlink
share/locale/nn/LC_MESSAGES/neon.mo: Could not unlink
share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/neon.mo: Could not unlink
share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/neon.mo: Could not unlink
share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/neon.mo: Could not unlink
share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/neon.mo: Could not unlink
share/doc/neon/html/api.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'share/doc/                                                            neon/html/api.html'
share/doc/neon/html/biblio.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'share/d                                                            oc/neon/html/biblio.html'
share/doc/neon/html/compliance.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'sha                                                            re/doc/neon/html/compliance.html'
share/doc/neon/html/features.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'share                                                            /doc/neon/html/features.html'
share/doc/neon/html/index.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'share/do                                                            c/neon/html/index.html'
share/doc/neon/html/intro.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'share/do                                                            c/neon/html/intro.html'
share/doc/neon/html/ref.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'share/doc/                                                            neon/html/ref.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refalloc.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'share                                                            /doc/neon/html/refalloc.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refauth.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'share/                                                            doc/neon/html/refauth.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refbuf.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'share/d                                                            oc/neon/html/refbuf.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refbufapp.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'shar                                                            e/doc/neon/html/refbufapp.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refbufcr.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'share                                                            /doc/neon/html/refbufcr.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refbufdest.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'sha                                                            re/doc/neon/html/refbufdest.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refbufutil.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'sha                                                            re/doc/neon/html/refbufutil.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refcert.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'share/                                                            doc/neon/html/refcert.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refclicert.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'sha                                                            re/doc/neon/html/refclicert.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refconfig.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'shar                                                            e/doc/neon/html/refconfig.html'
share/doc/neon/html/referr.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'share/d                                                            oc/neon/html/referr.html'
share/doc/neon/html/reffeat.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'share/                                                            doc/neon/html/reffeat.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refgetst.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'share                                                            /doc/neon/html/refgetst.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refi18n.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'share/                                                            doc/neon/html/refi18n.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refiaddr.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'share                                                            /doc/neon/html/refiaddr.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refneon.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'share/                                                            doc/neon/html/refneon.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refopts.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'share/                                                            doc/neon/html/refopts.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refreq.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'share/d                                                            oc/neon/html/refreq.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refreqbody.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'sha                                                            re/doc/neon/html/refreqbody.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refreqhdr.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'shar                                                            e/doc/neon/html/refreqhdr.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refreqflags.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'sh                                                            are/doc/neon/html/refreqflags.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refsessflags.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 's                                                            hare/doc/neon/html/refsessflags.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refresolve.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'sha                                                            re/doc/neon/html/refresolve.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refresphdr.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'sha                                                            re/doc/neon/html/refresphdr.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refsess.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'share/                                                            doc/neon/html/refsess.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refshave.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'share                                                            /doc/neon/html/refshave.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refsockinit.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'sh                                                            are/doc/neon/html/refsockinit.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refsslca.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'share                                                            /doc/neon/html/refsslca.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refsslcert2.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'sh                                                            are/doc/neon/html/refsslcert2.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refsslcertio.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 's                                                            hare/doc/neon/html/refsslcertio.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refssldname.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'sh                                                            are/doc/neon/html/refssldname.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refsslvfy.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'shar                                                            e/doc/neon/html/refsslvfy.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refstatus.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'shar                                                            e/doc/neon/html/refstatus.html'
share/doc/neon/html/reftok.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'share/d                                                            oc/neon/html/reftok.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refvers.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'share/                                                            doc/neon/html/refvers.html'
share/doc/neon/html/refxml.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'share/d                                                            oc/neon/html/refxml.html'
share/doc/neon/html/security.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'share                                                            /doc/neon/html/security.html'
share/doc/neon/html/using.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'share/do                                                            c/neon/html/using.html'
share/doc/neon/html/xml.html: Failed to create dir 'share/doc'Can't create 'share/doc/                                                            neon/html/xml.html'
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.

 eon/html/xml.html|/usr/bin/tar --unlink -xpPf - -C /usr/local
pkg_add: pkg_add of dependency 'neon29-0.29.5' failed!
Fetching ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/i386/packages-8.2-release/All/apr-ipv                                                            6-devrandom-gdbm-db42-1.4.2.1.3.10.tbz... Done.
pkg_add: could not find package db42-4.2.52_5 !
pkg_add: pkg_add of dependency 'apr-ipv6-devrandom-gdbm-db42-1.4.2.1.3.10' failed!
```

System detail :

```
[root@freenas] ~# df -h
    Filesystem             Size    Used   Avail Capacity  Mounted on
    /dev/ufs/FreeNASs1a    927M    404M    449M    47%    /
    devfs                  1.0K    1.0K      0B   100%    /dev
    /dev/md0               4.3M    3.6M    392K    90%    /etc
    /dev/md1               732K     16K    660K     2%    /mnt
    /dev/md2                75M     15M     53M    22%    /var
    /dev/ufs/FreeNASs4      20M    445K     18M     2%    /data
    /dev/ufs/Backup        226G     25G    183G    12%    /mnt/Backup

[root@freenas] ~# mount
/dev/ufs/FreeNASs1a on / (ufs, local, read-only, soft-updates)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, multilabel)
/dev/md0 on /etc (ufs, local)
/dev/md1 on /mnt (ufs, local)
/dev/md2 on /var (ufs, local)
/dev/ufs/FreeNASs4 on /data (ufs, local, noatime, soft-updates)
/dev/ufs/Backup on /mnt/Backup (ufs, local, soft-updates)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you've used embedded install for freenas instead of full (http://www.installationwiki.org/Installing_FreeNAS#Embedded_versus_Full) which means it's not really suitable for installing third party packages. You may want to use full install instead, it which case you likely won't need any additional tweaks.

In your case, though you may mount the root filesystem read-write with `mount -u /`, as your /var (which stores package database) is stored in memory and will be lost after reboot, you will have problems with deinstalling/updating installed packages and installing additional software, and other things may break. So I recommend to use Full install of FreeNAS.

Comment: I am running freenas from a 4 gig USB drive

Comment: yeah you are probably right.. I will try installing the full and see what happens